# Sorting an ArrayList<Comparable> With MergeSort Method

Tags: java

This is my Sorts class which has 3 different ways to sort int, Objects and ArrayLists.

```
public class Sorts {

/** <Selection Sort 1>
 * Sorts an array of data from low to high
 * pre: none
 * post: items has been sorted from low to high
 */
public static void selectionSort(int[] items) {

    for (int index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        for (int subIndex = index; subIndex < items.length; subIndex++) {
            if (items[subIndex] < items[index]) {
                int temp  = items[index];
                items[index] = items[subIndex];
                items[subIndex] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

/** <Selection Sort 2>
 * Sorts an array of objects from low to high
 * pre: none
 * post: Objects have been sorted from low to high
 */
public static void selectionSort(Comparable[] items) {

    for (int index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
        for (int subIndex = index; subIndex < items.length; subIndex++) {
            if (items[subIndex].compareTo(items[index]) < 0) {
                Comparable temp = items[index];
                items[index] = items[subIndex];
                items[subIndex] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

/** <Selection Sort 3>
 * Sorts an ArrayList
 * pre: none
 * post: Double objects have been sorted from low to high
 */
public static void selectionSort(ArrayList<Comparable> items) {

    for (int index = 0; index < items.size(); index++) {
        for (int subIndex = index; subIndex < items.size(); subIndex++) {
            if (items.get(subIndex).compareTo(items.get(index)) < 0) {
                Comparable temp = items.get(index);
                items.set(index, items.get(subIndex));
                items.set(subIndex, (Comparable) temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

/** <Insertion Sort 1>
 * Sorts an array of integers from low to high
 * pre: none
 * post: Integers have been sorted from low to high
 */
public static void insertionSort(int[] items) {
    int temp, previousIndex;

    for (int index = 1; index < items.length; index++) {
        temp = items[index];
        previousIndex = index - 1;
        while ((items[previousIndex] > temp) && (previousIndex > 0)) {
            items[previousIndex + 1] = items[previousIndex];
            previousIndex -= 1;     //decrease index to compare current
        }                           //item with next previous item
        if (items[previousIndex] > temp) {
            /* shift item in first element up into the next element */
            items[previousIndex + 1] = items[previousIndex];
            /* place current item at index 0 (first element) */
            items[previousIndex] = temp;
        } else {
            /* place current item at index ahead of previous item */
            items[previousIndex + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

/** <Insertion Sort 2>
 * Sorts an array of Strings in alphabetical order
 * pre: none
 * post: Strings have been sorted in alphabetical order
 */
public static void insertionSort(Comparable[] items) {
    int previousIndex;
    Comparable temp;

    for (int index = 1; index < items.length; index++) {
        temp = items[index];
        previousIndex = index - 1;
        while ((items[previousIndex].compareTo(temp)) > 0) {
            items[previousIndex + 1] = items[previousIndex];
            previousIndex -= 1;
        }
        if (items[previousIndex].compareTo(temp) > 0) {
            items[previousIndex + 1] = items[previousIndex];
            items[previousIndex] = temp;
        } else {
            items[previousIndex + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}

/** <Insertion Sort 3>
 * Sorts an ArrayList
 * pre: none
 * post: ArrayList is sorted
 */
public static void insertionSort(ArrayList<Comparable> items) {
    int previousIndex;
    Comparable temp;

    for (int index = 1; index < items.size(); index++) {
        temp = items.get(index);
        previousIndex = index - 1;
        while ((items.get(previousIndex).compareTo(temp)) > 0) {
            items.set(previousIndex + 1, items.get(previousIndex));
            previousIndex -= 1;
        }
        if (items.get(previousIndex).compareTo(temp) > 0) {
            items.set(previousIndex + 1, items.get(previousIndex));
            items.set(previousIndex, temp);
        } else {
            items.set(previousIndex + 1, temp);
        }
    }
}

/** <Merge Sort 1>
 * Merges two sorted portion of items array
 * pre: items[start..mid] is sorted. items[mid + 1..end] sorted.
 * start <= mid <= end                  >
 * post: items[start..end] is sorted.
 */
private static void merge(int[] items, int start, int mid, int end) {
    int[] temp = new int[items.length];
    int pos1 = start;
    int pos2 = mid + 1;
    int spot = start;

    while (!(pos1 > mid && pos2 > end)) {
        if ((pos1 > mid) || (pos2 <= end) && (items[pos2] < items[pos1])) {
            temp[spot] = items[pos2];
            pos2 += 1;
        } else {
            temp[spot] = items[pos1];
            pos1 += 1;
        }
        spot += 1;
    }
    /* copy values from temp back to items */
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        items[i] = temp[i];
    }
}

/**
 * Sorts items [start..end]
 * pre: start > 0, end > 0
 * post: items[start..end] is sorted low to high
 */
public static void mergesort(int[] items, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        mergesort(items, start, mid);
        mergesort(items, mid + 1, end);
        merge(items, start, mid, end);
    }
}

/** <Merge Sort 2>
 * Merges two sorted portion of items array
 * pre: items[start..mid] is sorted. items[mid + 1..end] sorted.
 * start <= mid <= end                                  >
 * post: items[start..end] is sorted.
 */
private static void merge(Comparable[] items, int start, int mid, int end) {
    Comparable[] temp = new Comparable[items.length];
    int pos1 = start;
    int pos2 = mid + 1;
    int spot = start;

    while (!(pos1 > mid && pos2 > end)) {
        if ((pos1 > mid) || (pos2 <= end) && (items[pos2].compareTo(items[pos1]) > 0)) {
            temp[spot] = items[pos2];
            pos2 += 1;
        } else {
            temp[spot] = items[pos1];
            pos1 += 1;
        }
        spot += 1;
    }
    /* copy values from temp back to items */
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        items[i] = temp[i];
    }
}

/**
 * Sorts items [start..end]
 * pre: start > 0, end > 0
 * post: items[start..end] is sorted low to high
 */
public static void mergesort(Comparable[] items, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        mergesort(items, start, mid);
        mergesort(items, mid + 1, end);
        merge(items, start, mid, end);
    }
}

/** <Merge Sort 3>
 * Merges two sorted portion of items array
 * pre: items[start..mid] is sorted. items[mid + 1..end] sorted.
 * start <= mid <= end                                  >
 * post: items[start..end] is sorted.
 */
private static void merge(ArrayList<Comparable> items, int start, int mid, int end) {
    ArrayList<Comparable> temp = new ArrayList<Comparable>(items.size());
    int pos1 = start;
    int pos2 = mid + 1;
    int spot = start;

    while (!(pos1 > mid && pos2 > end)) {
        if ((pos1 > mid) || (pos2 <= end) && (items.get(pos2).compareTo(items.get(pos1)) > 0)) {
            temp.set(spot, items.get(pos2));
            pos2 += 1;
        } else {
            temp.set(spot, items.get(pos1));
            pos1 += 1;
        }
        spot += 1;
    }
    /* copy values from temp back to items */
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        items.set(i, temp.get(i));
    }
}

/**
 * Sorts items [start..end]
 * pre: start > 0, end > 0
 * post: items[start..end] is sorted low to high
 */
public static void mergesort(ArrayList<Comparable> items, int start, int end) {
    if (start < end) {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        mergesort(items, start, mid);
        mergesort(items, mid + 1, end);
        merge(items, start, mid, end);
    }
}
```

}

Down at the bottom of the code is my Merge Sort Methods. The method I am having issues with working is MergeSort 3. Here is Merge Sort 3s TestSorts method which just gives it some String's to sort in alphabetical order.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/* Sorts objects with merge sort method */

public class MergeSort_3 {


public static void displayArray(ArrayList array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(array.get(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}

public static void sortStringArray() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numItems;
    ArrayList test;

    System.out.print("Enter number of elements: ");
    numItems = input.nextInt();

    /* populate and sort array */
    test = new ArrayList(numItems);
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String word = input.nextLine();
        test.add(i, word);
    }
    System.out.println("Unsorted:");
    displayArray(test);

    Sorts.mergesort(test, 0, test.size() - 1);

    System.out.println("Sorted:");
    displayArray(test);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    sortStringArray();
}
```

}

When I run the testSorts method, it crashes and I get an IndexOutOfBounds error that says that the size of my ArrayList is 0 as well as the index. I don't understand why this is happening since my other ones worked well. Could someone please examine my Sorts Merge Sort 3 to see if there is an error?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Not yet but my sorts class looks correct?